# python making bitmap data from 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bitmap, bmp

I have a device that accepts bitmap binary data. I would like to convert a numpy 2d array to bitmap and send it to this device. Currently what I do is to save the 2d array to a bitmap file, then read it into a variable and send that to the device. I'd like to skip the writing to the disk step. Is there an easy way to do that in Python?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways; go ahead and do it; ask a question if you face difficulties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) as a memory buffer to store the bitmap and send it without writing to disk.

As an example, assuming you use PIL or Pillow to save your bitmap file :

```
import io
from PIL import Image

image = Image.fromarray(numpy_array)
if image.mode != 'RGB':
    image = image.convert('RGB')

with io.BytesIO() as f:
    image.save(f, format='BMP')
    send_to_device(f)
```